# How extract strings between < and > with sed or awk

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I want extract all header files between < and >. I have a file called configure.ac from a git-repository. I want know which header files are present in this file. I would like to generate a list file with only header files. Example:

```
# _NL_MEASUREMENT_MEASUREMENT is an enum and not a define
AC_MSG_CHECKING([for _NL_MEASUREMENT_MEASUREMENT])
AC_LINK_IFELSE(
  [AC_LANG_PROGRAM(
    [[#include <langinfo.h>]],
    [[char c = *((unsigned char *)  nl_langinfo(_NL_MEASUREMENT_MEASUREMENT));]])],
  [nl_ok=yes],
  [nl_ok=no])
AC_MSG_RESULT($nl_ok)
if test "$nl_ok" = "yes"; then
  AC_DEFINE(HAVE__NL_MEASUREMENT_MEASUREMENT, 1,
        [Define to 1 if _NL_MEASUREMENT_MEASUREMENT is available])
fi

  if test "$ac_cv_header_sys_shm_h" = "yes"; then
    AC_MSG_CHECKING(whether shmctl IPC_RMID allowes subsequent attaches)
    AC_RUN_IFELSE(
      [AC_LANG_SOURCE([[
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/ipc.h>
    #include <sys/shm.h>
    int main()
    {
      int id;
      char *shmaddr;
    id = shmget (IPC_PRIVATE, 4, IPC_CREAT | 0600);
    if (id == -1)
      exit (2);
      shmaddr = shmat (id, 0, 0);
      shmctl (id, IPC_RMID, 0);
      if ((char*) shmat (id, 0, 0) == (char*) -1)
      {
        shmdt (shmaddr);
        exit (1);
      }
      shmdt (shmaddr);
      shmdt (shmaddr);
      exit (0);
    }
      ]])],
      [AC_DEFINE([IPC_RMID_DEFERRED_RELEASE],[1],
                 [Define to 1 if shared memory segments are released deferred.])
       AC_MSG_RESULT(yes)],
      [AC_MSG_RESULT(no)],
      [AC_MSG_RESULT(assuming no)])

    AC_DEFINE(USE_SYSV_SHM, 1, [Define to 1 to use SYSV shared memory])
  else
    shmtype=none
  fi
```

The output file must contain:

langinfo.h
types.h
ipc.h
shm.h
 

I tried:

```
echo "#include <stdio.h>" | sed -n 's/.*<\(.*\)\>.*/\1/p'
---> stdio.h

cat configure.ac | sed -n 's/.*<\(.*\)\>.*/\1/p' | sort -u > list.txt
---> It doesn't work
```

I can't find the error.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on your version of `sed`.  On Mac OS X 10.9.1 Mavericks (BSD `sed`), this works:

```
$ sed -n 's/.*\<\(.*\)\>.*/\1/p' data
langinfo.h
sys/types.h
sys/ipc.h
sys/shm.h
$
```

(where `data` is the fragment of `configure.ac` you quote in the question).  OTOH, GNU `sed` (version 4.2.2) gives (with the `...` being elided lines):

```
$  /usr/gnu/bin/sed -n 's/.*\<\(.*\)\>.*/\1/p' data
a
_NL_MEASUREMENT_MEASUREMENT
AC_LINK_IFELSE
AC_LANG_PROGRAM
h
_NL_MEASUREMENT_MEASUREMENT
yes
...
AC_LANG_SOURCE
h
h
h
main
id
shmaddr
...
else
shmtype
fi
$
```

Change the regex to:

```
$ /usr/gnu/bin/sed -n 's/.*<\(.*\)>.*/\1/p' data
langinfo.h
sys/types.h
sys/ipc.h
sys/shm.h
$
```

and the same output with BSD `sed`.

Moral: by default, the angle brackets `<>` are not metacharacters and do not need backslash escaping.

When they are escaped, they have a specific meaning (end of word or thereabouts).

Comment: Thank you. It works with: cat configure.ac | sed -n 's/.*<\(.*\)>.*/\1/p' | sort -u > list.txt

Comment: One of the frustrating things is that people have decided to change the rules about which regex system `sed` supports, so different platforms now support different variations.  It is a real pain!  And, to make things worse, sometimes they use options to change the behaviour explicitly (that's fine) and sometimes they seem to do things differently by default — whimsically, inconsistently and very frustratingly. Note that `sed` is quite capable of reading a file itself; you leave yourself open to charges of UUOC — Useless Use of `cat` — if you write `cat | sed`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. it's frustrating. I tought < and > are meta characters. \> means: Find the character at the beginning. The rules are not uniform and not clear. There are exceptions here and there.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if(/\<(.*?)\>/)' your_file
```